# How can I query INFORMATION_SCHEMA through Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, information-schema

I'm working on an app that uses metadata db information for analysis purposes, that is, query INFORMATION_SCHEMA and perform tasks based on the data.

In order to ease data manipulation, I implemented a code-first EF layer on top of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables/views. Why code first? because I didn't find a way to query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema through db first. So I come with:

```
[Table("INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA")]
internal class Schema
{
  #region Keys

  [Key, Column("CATALOG_NAME", Order = 0), MaxLength(256)]
  public string Catalog { get; set; }

  [Key, Column("SCHEMA_NAME", Order = 1), MaxLength(256)]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  #endregion Keys

  [Column("DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG")]
  public string DefaultCharacterSetforCatalog { get; set; }

  [Column("DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA")]
  public string DefaultCharacterSetforSchema { get; set; }

  [Column("DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME")]
  public string DefaultCharacterSetName { get; set; }

  [Column("SCHEMA_OWNER")]
  public string Owner { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is, when I try to read data using

```
  _informationSchema.Schemas.Load();
```

I get the message

```
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The specified schema name "INFORMATION_SCHEMA" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
```

As far as I know, this schema exists. And I can query it with SSMS, so it is not a matter of authorization. I think Maybe EF is preventing queries against INFORMATION_SCHEMA for security reasons? I googled this problem without much success.
The only alternate option I see would be to hard-code queries and loose strongly typed data. :(
Can someone please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using views maybe is the the best solution for you, as you only need to read the data, and the server can cache it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I read about this but the app shouldn't pollute the model with additional db objects. I could create them on the fly and remove them after use, but they would remain in case of app crash, which is not desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an exact answer to the question, but rather the best approach to the problem:

First, I read that INFORMATION_SCHEMA is not fully reliable (See [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)).
I had troubles with missing columns in my descriptions that made me come back to sys schema.

Next, when you install SSMS (Management Studio), which is free, it comes with a set of libraries which makes it super easy to navigate through the content of your model, and event perform some operations. These are:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended

Since 2017, these libraries also come as a nuget package:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-2017

Developping my app just went so smooth since I use this, I can only recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [FromSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) worked nicely for me:

```
internal class InformationSchemaColumn
{
    [Column("TABLE_NAME")]
    public string TableName { get; set; }

    [Column("COLUMN_NAME")]
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }

    [Column("IS_NULLABLE")]
    public string IsNullable { get; set; }

    [Column("CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH")]
    public int CharacterMaximumLength { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext 
{
  ....
  public IQueryable<InformationSchemaColumn> AllInformationSchemaColumns => AllInformationSchemaColumns.FromSql("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS");
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation and I want to share how I solved this problem, it was something simple.

The only thing I did was a view.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ViewSystemColums]
AS
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

And then I just mapped it into the Entity Framework to query the information.